# Swift navigation bar animation issue

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I am at a loss with what is potentially a simple fix.

I have a basic ViewController with a UINavigationController, and a UISearchBar embedded.
**Basic view layout**

[image]

When I PUSH a new UIViewController onto the Nav - I get a brief animation issue where a black background appears, and also the cancel button doesn't disappear.

**Animation glitch**

[image]

It's only brief, but annoying enough.

When I return back using the back button, the search bar reverts to white, and then switches to red.

**Back display issue**

[image]

I wondered if I had configured something wrong, so I created a fresh project and left everything with the defaults. Yet I get the same issue.

**Stripped back and the same issue**

[image]

I'm using xCode 9.3 - with swift 4.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `extendedLayout` settings of your view controllers (these can be set in code or in the storyboard editor). They need to be the same for both view controllers or you'll get this animation glitch.

In your case the problem might be the embedded search bar. It seems to be present only for one of the view controllers. You've got navigation bars with two different heights because of that. The framework doesn't respond well to that...

Comment: Thanks - I’ll  take a look. My main app is built all in code, but this test app is part storyboard and part code, so might account for this glitch.

Comment: Feel free to post the small test app. But this may just be a limitation of what a navigation controller can accommodate...

Comment: The below is a sample app that has the issue I am referring to. It seems to be specific to when a UISearchBar is within the NavBar.

https://github.com/MrBombHead/AppPlayground